# update title in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
public function updateMovie(Request $request, $id)
{
    $request->title;
    $movie = DB::connection('mysql2')->select('UPDATE cb_video SET title='.$request->title.' WHERE videoid=' . $id);
    return response()->json(['status' => 'success', 'data' => $movie]);
}
```

I am trying to update title in db but its throwing me error of

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE
> videoid=1449' at line 1 (SQL: UPDATE cb_video SET title= WHERE
> videoid=1449)

what can I do?

Comment: For heaven's sake it's 2023...parameterise your queries! Or better still use laravel's ready-made ORM...I've no idea why you'd bother to write such a simple query by hand instead of using the query builder. The issue you're having arises directly from not constructing the query properly...title (I assume) is a string, and you forgot to quote it. If you'd written the query in a sensible way that silly syntax error could never have occurred. And/or, from the dump it looks like title is actually empty...so you're trying to update it with a nonexistent value, possibly. That also makes no sense.

Comment: Read https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries and apply it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
DB::connection('mysql2')->table('cb_video')
->where('videoid', $id)
->update(['title' => $request->title]);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

there are many better ways in laravel than what you are doing you could use query builder or eloquent to do your task and in a secure way

for example

```
    public function updateMovie(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $movie = Your_Movie_Modal::findbyId($id);
        $movie->title = $request->title;
        $movie->update();
        return response()->json(['status' => 'success', 'data' => $movie]);
    }
```

and as I can see in your error it mean that you are not sending the title in the request

Comment: yes but i have to choose a specific database .. so how do i can work with db::connection?

Comment: in that case you could use #Arte Answer

Answer (score 1):

I hope you find this helpful

```
$title = 'New Title'; 

DB::table('table_name')->where('id', $id)->update(['title' => $title]);
```

Thanks